# Salesforce: Creating OpportunityLineItems as part of the Opportunity in PHP

Tags: php, soap, salesforce

I am trying to bulk upload 'Opportunities' into Salesforce using PHP Toolkit 20.0 and the Enterprise SOAP API.

The way I have found to do it is to create an Opportunity object and then create it in Salesforce via the SOAP API, then on the response I take the `Id` and use that for each 1..n OpportunityLineItems that exists for that Opportunity.

This isn't very efficient as it use 2 SOAP API calls and when done in bulk uses a lot of resources and is liable to timeouts. (I do not want to reduce the amount sent in one go as the API calls are limited)

**Therefore is there a way to create both the Opportunity and it's OpportunityLineItems in a single API call?**

I tried the following:

```
$opp = new stdClass();
$opp->Name = 'Opp1';
$opp->StageName = 'Closed Won';
$opp->Account = new stdClass();
$opp->Account->Custom_ID__c = '1234';
$opp->Pricebook2Id = '...'; 
$opp->OpportunityLineItems = array();
$opp->OpportunityLineItems[0] = new stdClass();
$opp->OpportunityLineItems[0]->Description = 'Product name';
$opp->OpportunityLineItems[0]->Quantity = 1;
$opp->OpportunityLineItems[0]->UnitPrice = 10.00;
...
$opp->OpportunityLineItems[n] = new stdClass();
$opp->OpportunityLineItems[n]->Description = 'Product name';
$opp->OpportunityLineItems[n]->Quantity = 1;
$opp->OpportunityLineItems[n]->UnitPrice = 10.00;
```

But it resulted in:
`INVALID_FIELD: No such column 'OpportunityLineItems' on entity 'Opportunity'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.`
Which was to be expected as the WSDL file states that OpportunityLineItems is of type `tns:QueryResult` rather than an `ens:`

Comment: Really nice question, I'm curious! But if the count of API requests really a concern, could you simply pay for couple more user licenses, each giving you 1-5K calls more? https://eu1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/integrate_api_rate_limiting.htm. Also - is creation of Apex webservice class that would accept Opportunity and array of OLIs in one go a valid alternative?

Comment: @eyescream Boss says no to Licences, the Apex webservice is a nice idea and one I'll look into, but I don't have the skillset right now so a PHP solution is still the ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**: Complete overhaul to show how multiple opps can be added at same time. Should be useful if you can stagger their creation somehow (store them in your local database and upload only when you got a couple/sufficient time has passed/user pressed "flush the queue" button).

Warning, the code actually looks more scary now, you might be better of checking [previous version](/posts/13273213/revisions) in edit history first.

It won't be too hard to create an Apex class that would accept incoming request with 2 parameters and attempt to insert them. Go to Setup->Develop->Classes->New and try this:

```
global with sharing class OpportunityLinkedInsert{

    static webservice Opportunity insertSingle(Opportunity opp, OpportunityLineItem[] lines){
        if(opp == null || lines == null){
            throw new IntegrationException('Invalid data');
        }
        Opportunity[] result = insertMultiple(new List<Opportunity>{opp}, new List<List<OpportunityLineItem>>{lines});
        return result[0]; // I imagine you want the Id back :) 
    }

    /*  I think SOAP doesn't handle method overloading well so this method has different name.
        'lines' are list of lists (jagged array if you like) so opps[i] will be inserted and then lines[i] will be linked to it etc.

        You can insert up to 10,000 rows in one go with this function (remember to count items in both arrays).
    */
    static webservice List<Opportunity> insertMultiple(List<Opportunity> opps, List<List<OpportunityLineItem>> lines){
        if(opps == null || lines == null || opps.size() == 0 || opps.size() != lines.size()){
            throw new IntegrationException('Invalid data');
        }
        insert opps;

        // I need to flatten the structure before I insert it.
        List<OpportunityLineItem> linesToInsert = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();

        for(Integer i = 0; i < opps.size(); ++i){
            List<OpportunityLineItem> linesForOne = lines[i];
            if(linesForOne != null && !linesForOne.isEmpty()){
                for(Integer j = 0; j < linesForOne.size(); ++j){
                    linesForOne[j].OpportunityId = opps[i].Id;
                }
                linesToInsert.addAll(linesForOne);
            }
        }
        insert linesToInsert;
        return opps;
    }

    // helper class to throw custom errors
    public class IntegrationException extends Exception{}
}
```

You'll also need an unit test class before this can go to your production organisation. Something like that should do (needs to be filled with couple more things before being 100% usable, [see this question for more info](/questions/9164986/how-do-i-avoid-standard-price-not-defined-when-unit-testing-an-opportunitylineit)).

```
@isTest
public class OpportunityLinkedInsertTest{
    private static List<Opportunity> opps;
    private static List<List<OpportunityLineItem>> items;

    @isTest
    public static void checSingleOppkErrorFlow(){
        try{
            OpportunityLinkedInsert.insertSingle(null, null);
            System.assert(false, 'It should have failed on null values');
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.assertEquals('Invalid data',e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @isTest
    public static void checkMultiOppErrorFlow(){
        prepareTestData();
        opps.remove(1);

        try{
            OpportunityLinkedInsert.insertMultiple(opps, items);
            System.assert(false, 'It should have failed on list size mismatch');
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.assertEquals('Invalid data',e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @isTest
    public static void checkSuccessFlow(){
        prepareTestData();
        List<Opportunity> insertResults = OpportunityLinkedInsert.insertMultiple(opps, items);

        List<Opportunity> check = [SELECT Id, Name, 
            (SELECT Id FROM OpportunityLineItems) 
            FROM Opportunity 
            WHERE Id IN :insertResults 
            ORDER BY Name];
        System.assertEquals(items[0].size(), check[0].OpportunityLineItems.size(), 'Opp 1 should have 1 product added to it');
        System.assertEquals(items[1].size(), check[0].OpportunityLineItems.size(), 'Opp 3 should have 1 products');
    }

    // Helper method we can reuse in several tests. Creates 2 Opportunities with different number of line items.
    private static void prepareTestData(){
        opps = new List<Opportunity>{
            new Opportunity(Name = 'Opp 1', StageName = 'Prospecting', CloseDate = System.today() + 10),
            new Opportunity(Name = 'Opp 2', StageName = 'Closed Won', CloseDate = System.today())
        };

        // You might have to fill in more fields here!
        // Products are quite painful to insert with all their standard/custom pricebook dependencies etc...
        items = new List<List<OpportunityLineItem>>{
            new List<OpportunityLineItem>{
                new OpportunityLineItem(Description = 'Opp 1, Product 1', Quantity = 1, UnitPrice = 10)
            },
            new List<OpportunityLineItem>{
                new OpportunityLineItem(Description = 'Opp 2, Product 1', Quantity = 1, UnitPrice = 10),
                new OpportunityLineItem(Description = 'Opp 2, Product 2', Quantity = 1, UnitPrice = 10),
                new OpportunityLineItem(Description = 'Opp 2, Product 3', Quantity = 1, UnitPrice = 10)
            }
        };
    }
}
```

---

That's pretty much in terms of Apex code.

If either of inserts will fail you'll get a SOAP Exception back. This is also a bit better in terms of transactions, [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) etc - if insert of your line items will fail, are you prepared to clean it up from PHP side? What if some automated email notifications etc. were set up in Salesforce and already sent? Having it in one call to Apex will make sure whole request will be rolled back, pretty much like stored procedures work in the databases.

Try to create these classes in sandbox, then locate first one on the list of classes. It will have a link to generate a WSDL file which you can use to generate your PHP classes.
Going to the second one you'll see a "Run Tests" button. You'll have to make sure the test passes before pushing it to your production org - but that's whole new world of [programming on the platform](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex) for you :)

Comment: Thanks for this. I haven't yet got it to work (skillset issues), but it's defiantly the right way go.

Comment: Once again thank you this is just what we need. I added this and the unit test to my sandbox. Ran the test, got the WSDL file and then tried to access it but got a Saleforce UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION which I have reported to Salesforce support.

Comment: @PhilCarter weird, try mine while you wait for them: http://pastebin.com/uAKUxAk7 You'll have to modify the endpoint at the bottom of the file (mine points to "Developer Edition" at na5.salesforce.com). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13184262/313628 for more explanations. You can probably cannibalize the hell out of it as I can see it has all my objects... experiment with <xsd:element name="insertMultiple"> at the bottom :)