# Access Custom Field Salesforce

Tags: java, salesforce, apex-code, force.com

I have a created a custom field in Contacts object in Salesforce whose API name is "Resume_Text__c" and I'm making a SOAP call to get the value of that filed using Java Implementation by writing a following SOQL.

```
SELECT  Resume_Text__c FROM Contact
```

But execution  of query throwing following exception.

```
No such column 'Resume_Text__c' on entity 'Contact'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.'
```

So how can I access custom field via Soap API Java Implementation?

Comment: Are you sure that the field is visible for the user whose credentials are used in the integration? I'm talking mostly about "field level security". Or is there any chance you've made the field in Sandbox but are logging in to Production? ;)

Comment: I have created field in production environment and I am using credentials for same account.

Comment: com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: unable to find end tag at:  START_TAG seen ...<sf:Id xsi:nil="true"/><sf:Resume_Text__c>... @1:427

Comment: Looks like unexpected field. Are you using the "Enterprise WSDL" by any chance? You'll have to regenerate it from SF and consume (refresh classes generated from it) in your Java app. Partner WSDL is more flexible but doesn't explicitly list all the fields and objects.

Comment: Yes I'm using Enterprise WSDL. But I am not able to able to understand, why do we need to refresh it, as I generated it from SF some 15 days ago. Can you share the reason for refreshing it?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I regenerated WSDL.

Comment: Partner WSDL is identical in any org, talks about generic sObjects, it's more work for your app to use describe() calls to learn what objects are there and what fields do they have. Enterprise one has all this data so you generate your Account, Contact etc classes right away. But it means you need to refresh it every time you want to access new fields or objects. I wrote a bit about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13184262/313628 Gotta run now, wish you luck :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you are using **Enterprise.wsdl** file in your implementation, you need to make sure that every time you create some new fields and object on Salesforce.com environment, you **refresh your Enterprise.wsdl** to import all the dependency mappings else go with **Partner.wsdl**.