# Externally configuring a WSDL location in the maven-jaxb2-plugin

Tags: java, maven, wsdl, jaxb2

I'm trying to call an external SOAP service within my Java application. To do this I want to generate the request and response objects from the wsdl exposed on some domain. I'm using the maven-jaxb2-plugin to do this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.13.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    <configuration>
        <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
        <generatePackage>example.wsdl</generatePackage>
        <schemas>
            <schema>
                <url>http://someaddress/example.wsdl</url>
            </schema>
        </schemas>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The thing is: I want to be able to able to change the URL of the WSDL (http://someaddress/example.wsdl) depending on what environment the application is going to be deployed to. I was thinking of using System properties to do this but is there some better practice to achieve this?

EDIT: After more searching I have found a similar questions but in a C# context. Might this help with coming up with a solution? [How can you use two WSDLs and maintain a test instance with a C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181228/how-can-you-use-two-wsdls-and-maintain-a-test-instance-with-a-c-sharp-applicatio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

The example of configuration below:

```
<!-- Profile configuration -->
<profiles>
    <!-- The configuration of the development profile -->
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <!-- The development profile is active by default -->
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
          <build.profile.url>http://someaddress/example.wsdl</build.profile.url>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <!-- The configuration of the production profile -->
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
         <build.profile.url>http://someaddress/example2.wsdl</build.profile.url>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <!-- The configuration of the testing profile -->
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <properties>
           <build.profile.url>http://someaddress/example3.wsdl</build.profile.url>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

and then in your plugin

```
<schemas>
        <schema>
            <url>${build.profile.url}</url>
        </schema>
    </schemas>
```

To install artifact with profile `dev` use

```
mvn clean install -P dev
```